# Python edit variable in separate module

Tags: python, variables, module

I've found plenty about calling variables from another module, but I can't find anything about editing a variable in a separate module.

For my first actual project with python I'm writing a little text adventure.

I've got GV.py for global variables, and Classes.py for weapons/armor etc.

I want Classes.Longsword() to modify a variable in GV.py, specifically variable GV.weapon.

In GV.py

```
import Classes
global weapon
weapon = 'Unarmed'
```

in Classes.py

```
import GV
def Longsword():
    GV.weapon = 'Longsword'
```

This does not edit the variable weapon in GV.py.. Am I missing something?

Since it was asked I'll put the output here.

repl from GV.py

```
weapon
'Unarmed'
Classes.Longsword()
>>>>
weapon
'Unarmed'
```

Comment: Did you actually *call* the function?

Comment: yes. running the repl from GV.py. If I call the function the variable weapon does not change.

Comment: So.. I see what its doing.. its creating a local GV.weapon IN Classes.py.. not quite what I want it to do though.

Comment: No, it's not creating a local `GV`, or a local `GV.weapon`. I think I know where your mind is heading, but that's a rare problem, and one you only run into if you start doing `import`s inside a function definition.

Comment: Meanwhile, what does "repl from GV.py" mean? I assume it means you're doing something like `python -i GV.py`, but I'm not _sure_ about that.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that, when you run the script `GV.py`, what you get isn't a module named `GV`, but a special module named `__main__`.

---

If you've seen the familiar main guard idiom, that can be used to write a single file that works as a module or as a top-level script, this is exactly how it works:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

That will be true when you're running the file as a script, and it will not be true when you're importing the file as a module.

---

Now, when you do `import GV` from inside `Classes`, that imports the exact same `GV.py` file, and builds a second module object out of it (and this one, of course, *is* named `GV`).

So when you then do `GV.weapon = 'longsword'`, you're changing the `weapon` global in the `GV` module, not the `__main__` module.

---

If you're wondering how this works under the covers: the way Python makes sure there's only one `Classes` module object no matter how many times you `import Classes` is dead simple: it just caches loaded modules in a dict, [`sys.modules`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.modules), and looks them up by name.

---

If you fix that, you've got a second problem here: the first thing `GV.py` does is to `import Classes`. The first thing `Classes.py` does is to `import GV`. This is a circular import.

---

The usual way to deal with *both* of these problems is pretty simple: put the shared globals in a simple module that does little or nothing beyond holding those shared globals, so everyone can `import` it:

```
# main.py
import classes
import GV
GV.weapon = 'Unarmed'

# Classes.py
import GV
def Longsword():
    GV.weapon = 'Longsword'

# GV.py
# empty... or you can move weapon = 'Unarmed' here
```

Comment: Ohhh, ok. That makes a ton of sense.. just tested it and it functioned as expected. Thank you so much! I'd been googling for hours.

Comment: @JohnFarley Yeah, it's one of those things that's hard to google for unless you already know the answer you're looking for. (If you search for `__main__` you'll find lots of answers, but how could you know to search for `__main__`?)